# How to change the email verification link in allauth

Tags: django, angularjs

I'm using allauth in my django application. Once the user is created it sends an email with the link like this `http://localhost:8001/account/confirm-email/asdfafsd/`

However, I want the link to be `http://localhost:8001/verifyEmail/asdfafsd` since I am using angular on the front end.

I can't figure out where to change this link?

Answer (score 4):

1. Override the template by creating a same named file. 
   For django-allauth: `templates/account/email_confirmation_message.txt`
2. create a sample custom tag and include in any of your app, i.e 
   for example app `userprofile` in `userprofile/templatetags/userprofile.py`
3. in `userprofile.py`code can be like

   ```
   from django import template
   from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

   register = template.Library()



   @register.simple_tag(name="make_confirm_url", takes_context=True)
   def make_confirm_url(context):
       activate_url = context.get('activate_url')
       slice_idx = activate_url.find('account')
       return ''.join(['http://', context.get('current_site').domain, '/',activate_url[slice_idx:]])
   ```
4. `email_confirmation_message.txt` can be like

   ```
   {% load userprofile %}{% make_confirm_url as the_link %}
   {% load account %}{% user_display user as user_display %}{% load i18n %}
   {% autoescape off %}{% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.namesite_domain=current_site.domain %}
   Hello from {{ site_name }}!

   You're receiving this e-mail because user {{ user_display }} has given yours as an e-mail address to connect their account.

   To confirm this is correct, go to {{the_link}}
   {% endblocktrans %}{% endautoescape %}
   {% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.name site_domain=current_site.domain %}Thank you from {{ site_name }} Dev Team !
   {{ site_domain }}{% endblocktrans %}
   ```
5. In the above code the domain is fetched from the django_sites Model You can include you logics and write a route accordingly in frontend framework (like angular). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem!

Instead of changing the URL by changing the template (which wasn't working for me for some odd reason), I came up with two other solutions.

### Solution 1:

to overwrite the ***get_email_confirmation_url()*** method in the [***Default Account Adapter***](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/adapter.py).

So, in my Django Project, I made an app called 'users,' and in the users app I made an adapter.py.

In the adapter.py (Note 1: the get_adapter indent is ***on purpose***, it should be in the bottom of the file not in the class.
| Note 2: You can replace ***your_url_here***, but do not replace ***emailconfirmation.key*** as it is the key that is used to confirm the email!):

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from allauth.account import app_settings
from allauth.utils import import_attribute

class CustomAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def get_email_confirmation_url(self, request, emailconfirmation):
        url = your_url_here + emailconfirmation.key
        return URL

def get_adapter(request=None):
    """
    The Adapter in app_settings.ADAPTER is set to CustomAccountAdapter.
    """
    return import_attribute(app_settings.ADAPTER)(request)
```

After that, make sure that you have also properly configured ***ACCOUNT_ADAPTER*** in settings.py:

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'users.adapter.CustomAccountAdapter'
```

### Solution 2:

The second solution, the one I ended up going with, is to name my frontend URL in my main urls.py (my Angular app is hosted through my Django App). So, assuming you have a similar sort of setup:

```
path('auth/confirm-email/<str:key>',
    TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"),
    name="account_confirm_email"
),
```

### Resources:

I would really recommend reading through:

- The [Default Account Adapter](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/adapter.py) Code!
- The [Allauth docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html)!
- The [Allauth Views](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py)!

Answer (score 1):

Add to urls.py custom URL:

`url(r"^verifyEmail/(?P<key>\w+)/$", allauth.accounts.views.confirm_email, name="my_confirm_email")`

And edit email-template to use 'my_confirm_email' url:

http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#sending-e-mail

Comment: How can I edit the email-template? I can't find the file`account/email/email_confirmation_message.txt` anywhere in the code.

Comment: This doesn't seem like what I want. the `verifyEmail` URL is already made in my angular app and works perfectly fine. All I want to do is change the URL in the email sent to the user to that same `verifyEmail` url rather than `http://localhost:8001/account/confirm-email/asdfafsd/`

Comment: this is the URL I'm trying to change https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html#L6

Comment: You said that you want change allauth email verification url, but link to github lead to django's user password reset email template. All you need to do is to create url on server-side. You done it only in client-side via angularjs. To change url in email, you should create your custom email template, that override standard template from allauth. To do it, you need copy templates directory from allauth to your project's templates directory and edit template for email verification.