# How to change the Django-allauth default url patterns?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

while using the django-allauth as the registeration system, the following codes work well:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...
]
```

so, under this settings:

- when the user wants to signin, then go to 'example.com/accounts/login'
- when the user wants to signup, then go to 'example.com/accounts/singup'
- ...

but now I want to change the urls to something like:

- when the user wants to signin, then go to 'example.com/**staff**/login'
- when the user wants to signup, then go to 'example.com/**staff**/singup'
- ...

I just want to change **'accounts'** in the urls to **'staff'**.

I've just tried to revise the urls.py to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('staff/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

most of the registration funcitons worked well, except the email comfirmtion.

I reveived the confirmation email and clicked on the comfirmation button, but then the redirect url will always be 'example.com/**accounts**/login', which raise a 404 error.

I want to know how to fix this problem, I will:

- fix it, if this can be done in a few steps
- use the default settings, if this is complicated or will bring some risks.

Versions:

- Python: 3.8.1
- Django: 3.0.4
- Django-allauth:0.41.0

I am a freshman on coding (and English), thank you very very much.

Comment: Can we see your views.py to see how you generate the email sending

Comment: I didn't write any views.py or apps in my django project to generate the email sending precess.After starting the django project, I immediately 'installed' the django-allauth into the settings.py and then I found this problem. I think the email sending is generated all by the django-allauth itself.

Comment: Then you need to customize it and use your own

Comment: understood,  I think it is better for me to use the default settings. Thank you very much Wariored!

Comment: Take a look over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412226/how-to-change-the-email-verification-link-in-allauth